# Rails HABTM association not clearing using .clear, thoughts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

High guys.  This isn't behaving the way I think it should which means I'm doing it wrong;

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :properties
end

class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags

  def amenities
    tags.where(:classification => :amenity)
  end
end
```

So I have Properties and Tags.  They have a HABTM relationship with a pivot table.

When I do a `.tags` on a property, I get the full list and if I do a `.clear` on that full list it correctly removes the associations from the database.

When I do a `.amenities` I get only those tags that are flagged with the classification of amenity correctly, but if I do a `.clear` on those results it fails to remove them but rather just does the `.amenities` query again in the console with an output of `[]`.

So this means it's just `.clear`'ing the result array.. not the association which is what I actually want.

So the question then is; what is the correct way to `.clear` an association from a HABTM relationship while giving it essentially a `where` clause to limit which associations are being removed?

Thanks guys.  Hope that wasn't too confusing..

Comment: `.clear` is method created for only collection association: `collection.clear`, so I think you can not use it with your own method. Maybe you can use `destroy_all` method, ex: `@property.tags.amenities.destroy_all`

Comment: `.destroy_all` actually "destroys" the tag, not just removing the association..  I need the association destroyed, not the tags..  Close though!

Comment: Also `.delete_all` tries to delete from the Tags table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of defining a method querying tags, you could add another tag association with conditions, like:

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags

  # this will be just like the tags association, except narrow the results
  # to only tags with the classification of 'amenity'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :amenities, 
                          :class_name => 'Tag', 
                          :conditions => { :classification => 'amenity' }

end
```

`clear`, and any other habtm assocation methods, should work as expected.